# how to call a url through load() function in php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I am calling a url to get content in `div`. I am using javascript function to call it. I am using this code

```
<div class="portlet" data-id="prt2">
      <div class="portlet-header">Reporting</div>
      <div class="portlet-content" id="divEmployeeReportingWidget"></div>
</div>
<script>AjaxPage('../home/pages.php?page=Dashboard_EmployeeReporting', 'divEmployeeReportingWidget');</script>
```

and the function is here:

```
function AjaxPage(url, containerid)
{
   $("#"+containerid).html('<br /><br /><div align="center"><img src="images/loading.gif" /></div><br /><br />');
   var j = $("#"+containerid).load(url);    
}
```

and the page.php is here:

```
if($_REQUEST['page'] == 'Dashboard_EmployeeReporting'){
echo '<div class="portlet-content" id="divEmployeeReportingWidget"><table border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" width="98%" align="center">
     <tbody><tr><td style="width:100px;" valign="top">Report To:</td><td class="main2"><span style="font-weight:bold;"><img src="../images/icons/iconUser.gif" style="float:left">&nbsp;John Smith<br></span></td></tr>
     <tr><td valign="top">Reporting To Me:</td><td class="main2"><span style="font-weight:bold;"></span></td></tr>
    </tbody></table></div>';
}
```

I am unable to get content. How can I do that ?

Comment: Is the page.php called? Did you use firebug or something similar to check, which page is called and what the server returns?

Comment: I don't know how to check it through this load function. coz i am calling this page through load() function

Comment: Have a look at your browser's developer tools to see all the requests which are made. [Chrome example](http://paste.jdsv.de/static/img/150212-54dc55df12a6b.png). You have to know if your page.php was even called and if it returned something.